# C++ Error: error: expected unqualified-id before string constant

Tags: c++, string

What should I do in this line of code (highlighted by comment) ?

```
# include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int occurrences = 0;
    std::string::size_type start = 0;
    std::string base_string = "Hello World in C++!";
    std::string to_find_occurrences_of = "o","+"; // error

    while ((start = base_string.find(to_find_occurrences_of, start)) != std::string::npos) {
        ++occurrences;
        start += to_find_occurrences_of.length();
}
    std::cout<<occurrences;
    return 0;
}
```

I want `string to_find_occurrences_of = "o","+"` to print the two characters in one time (but IDE raises an error) because I do not want to define the string (and the function) over and over again to find the occurrences of the characters in `string base_string` one by one.

It may sound like a stupid question, but I want to know the solution to this error.

Thank you to anyone who may be reading this question or answering!!!

Comment: Use a `std::string` array?

Comment: Your question isn't clear to me. What output are you expecting from this program?

Comment: Maybe you need a string array (like Jason says) and an extra loop to process each string in turn. But it's not really clear. What is clear is that you're making up your own language. You can't write code like `"o","+"` and expect C++ somehow to understand what you mean.

Comment: Are we to assume that `4` is the output you're expecting? And is there any particular reason you're not just using a ranged for across a string `"o+"` and an accumulator via `std::count`, or `count_if` and a lambda, or a lookup table, or any number of other options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::string to_find_occurrences_of = "o","+";`  won't compile, because you have two strings, rather than one.

You could just have an initialiser list of the things to find:

```
int main()
{
    int occurrences = 0;
    // std::string::size_type start = 0; // need to reset for each character
    std::string base_string = "Hello World in C++!";
    for (std::string to_find_occurrences_of : { "o", "+" }) // OK
    {
        std::string::size_type start = 0; // start from the beginning for each character
        while ((start = base_string.find(to_find_occurrences_of, start)) != std::string::npos) {
            ++occurrences;
            start += to_find_occurrences_of.length();
        }
    }
    std::cout << occurrences;
}
```

Comment: But how should I print the occurrences of  "+" (It just prints occurrence of "o") ?

Comment: You need to wind start back in the for loop - I'll edit the answer

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But, for one last question, is there a way to print the occurrences of the characters out like I know occurrence of `o` is 2, and occurrence of `+` is 2 but rather not the total?

Comment: Put `int occurrences = 0;` inside the for loop, and the `std::cout << occurrences;` as well.  Or even say ``std::cout << to_find_occurrences_of << " found " << occurrences;`` so it says which letter

Answer (score 0):

You can use a std::vector of string instead:

```
# include <iostream>
# include <vector>

int main()
{
    int occurrences = 0;
    std::string::size_type start = 0;
    std::string base_string = "Hello World in C++!";
    std::vector<std::string> to_find_occurrences_of;
    to_find_occurrences_of.push_back("o");
    to_find_occurrences_of.push_back("+");
    
    for (size_t i = 0; i < to_find_occurrences_of.size(); i++){
        start = 0;
        while ((start = base_string.find(to_find_occurrences_of.at(i),start)) != std::string::npos) {
        ++occurrences;
        start += to_find_occurrences_of.at(i).length();
    }
}
std::cout<<occurrences;
return 0;
```

}